# How to check the HOST using ExpressJS?

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js, express

I have to check the `HOST` of the http request, if it's equal to `example.com` or `www.example.com`, I have to do a 301 redirect.

How can I do this using Node.js and Express Web Framework?

Comment: The HOST of an http request is part of the header. The request object passed to your callback has a .header() method. Did you try reading the documentation at all?

Answer (score 18):

Use

```
req.headers.host;
```

or

```
req.header('host');
```

Both will return you host name. e.g `localhost:3000`

Answer (score 5):

[Express.js guide - request.hostname](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.hostname)

[Express.js guide - request.redirect](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.redirect)

Comment: Yes i Know, but how to check if it equals to example.com or www.example.com ?

Answer (score 5):

`req.header('host')`

Use that in your request handlers.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `req.headers.host`?

Answer (score 2):

Do a string search, using a regular expression, as so:

```
if ( req.headers.host.search(/^www/) !== -1 ) {
  res.redirect(301, "http://example.com/");
}
```

The search method accepts a regular expression as the first argument, denoted by surrounding slashes. The first character, ^, in the expression means to explicitly look at the beginning of the string. The rest of the expression is looking for three explicit w's. If the string begins with "www", then the search method will return the index of match, if any (0), or -1, if it wasn't found.

Answer (score 1):

Today for me it's req.host, req.hostname and req.headers.host - I'm going with req.host though.
**update** vscode tells me req.host is deprecated and use req.hostname instead