# Retrieve domain name from node in shared hosting

Tags: node.js, api, curl

Hi have a NodeJs app in a shared hosting, where I'm trying to make API calls. Lets say my domain is example.com.

```
'http://localhost:' + global.PORT_SERVER + url + id
```

This works in local, because localhost is my machine; but in the server, as it's a shared hosting, the hostname is not my domain, but `hl358.hostingexample.com`.

```
$ hostname
$ hl358.hostingexample.com
```

Now with CURL from ssh, this works:

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" "http://example.com:80/api/projects"
```

and this don't:

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" "http://localhost:80/api/projects"
```

If I try to retrieve mydomain.com from node 'os' I still get `hl318.hostingexample.com`:

```
$ node
> const os = require('os')
> os.hostname()
'hl358.hostingexample.com'
```

No I'm a bit lost. Does anyone know how to retrieve actual domain with node?

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/a/20554225/4934937 ?

Comment: Thanks @maio290. Yes, I did.