# can we detect hostname and apply condition into the env file Nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

can we detect hostname and apply condition into the env file

for example in the env file in NodeJs project

```
FRONTURL = location.window.hostname == 'staging.xyz.com' ? 'stage.com' : 'live.com';
```

Comment: You won't have access to the window object in Node.js environment. You just can't change the env on the run.  Can you explain it a bit to what do you want to do and how are you doing it right now?

Comment: Actually we have FRONTENDURL and we would like to pass it dynamically e.g if hosting url says staging.domain.com then FRONTENDURL should says staging.domain.com and if hosting urls says domain.com then FRONTENDURL should says domain.com which is maintainly from env file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node JS return hostname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20553554/node-js-return-hostname)