# node.js server get host name without req

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

At present I'm using `req.headers.host` to determine the server's host name, which is effective when processing a request received at the server.

But how can one determine the host name in the absence of a request (i.e. without `req`)?  I'm thinking, in particular, when the node server is first created and run, and before any requests are received.

I'm using the `express` module.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9399767/2182767 - check this answer

Comment: If there is no request, you don't actually know the hostname.  A single server can serve multiple hostnames.

Comment: I only have low-level experience of Cloud 9 IDE and heroku, and in both of those (at least to the level I'm working) you access the node server via a specific URL.  So with C9 when you start the server it says "Your code is running at https://xxx.yyy.com", while with heroku you're assigned a specific URL for your server.  So, when I start the same server on C9 and on heroku, how do I know whether it's running on C9 or heroku?  I had hoped I could do this just by checking the hostname, like I can do on receiving a request.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the os module and `os.hostname()`

https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/os.html#os_os_hostname

Comment: The local hostname is usually different from the hostname(s) served through HTTP.

Comment: Will hostname be the same each time the server is restarted on the same host?

Comment: this is returning machine name how to get real host name ie 'localhost'?

Comment: @user3797053 that is the "real" machine name.