# How to extract domain name of a request coming from a url, using request module -Node js

Tags: node.js, express, npm, request

there I want to extract the domain name of incoming request using request module. I tried by looking at

```
request.headers,
request.headers.hostname
```

with no luck. Any help please?

Comment: If you're using the `request()` module, then you are making a request TO another site so you should already know the domain name.  There is no domain name on the response that comes back from the request.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get hostname of current request in node.js Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7507015/get-hostname-of-current-request-in-node-js-express)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Client domain is available at origin.

```
request.headers.origin
```

for ex:

```
if(request.headers.origin.indexOf('gowtham') > -1) {
   // do something
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `request.headers.host` .

Comment: host gives the domain name where the program is running. I need to extract  the domain in middleware, who is actually made the request.

Answer (score 0):

So you want the domain name of the client that is making the request?

Since Express only provides you with their IP-address, you have to [reverse-lookup](https://nodejs.org/api/dns.html#dns_dns_reverse_ip_callback) that IP-address to get the hostname. From there, you can extract the domain name.

In a middleware

```
const dns = require('dns');
...
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  dns.reverse(req.ip, function(err, hostnames) {
    if (! err) {
      console.log('domain name(s):', hostnames.map(function(hostname) {
        return hostname.split('.').slice(-2).join('.');
      }));
    }
    next();
  });
});
```

However, very big disclaimer: making a DNS lookup for every request can have a severe performance impact.