# How to split domain with http or https in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

Anyone can help to split the domain name with http or https from url string,

```
URL : https://www.test.com/abc/?a=1&b=1

Expected Output : https://www.test.com
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7507015/get-hostname-of-current-request-in-node-js-express

Comment: `url.match(/https:\/\/(www.)?[a-zA-Z].[a-zA-Z]\//)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I strongly recommend you avoid using a home-grown regexp. Instead, use the node `URL` class:

https://nodejs.org/api/url.html

Not exactly sure which parts you want to keep or not (do you want to include the port? Do you want to decode IDNs?), but `origin` may be the way to go. Here’s the example straight out from the docs:

```
const { URL } = require('url');
const myURL = new URL('https://example.org/foo/bar?baz');
console.log(myURL.origin);
// Prints https://example.org
```

Otherwise, you could use the `protocol` and `host` or `hostname` components.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the url-parse package also for get the origin from URL,

Refer : https://www.npmjs.com/package/url-parse

```
var URL = require('url-parse');
const url_obj = new URL('https://test.com/abc/?a=1');
console.log(url_obj.origin); // https://test.com
```