# Multiple websites pointing to a Node.js application, extract hostname

Tags: node.js, reactjs, vhosts

I have a Node.js React application that outputs different information fetched from an external API depending on the domain provided in the request as a variable.

I'm looking to point hundreds of domains to the application, and need to extract the root domain (that was used to access the app) to then use in the API request.

How can I do this at scale, considering I'll have many domains and can't be editing a vhost file every time?

```
DNS: domain1.com CNAME domains.example.com    
App: Vistor goes to "https://domain1.com/example" -> *var domain = "domain1.com"* -> Customized page output
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4062281/6419723 ???

Comment: Please add code, show us what you tried already and what is the main issue you are facing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you're using Express or not, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7507507/1649666) might point you in the right direction. Your server should be able to look at the `Host` header on the request. I think all HTTP requests *must* include a `Host` header ([documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Messages)), but the way it's exposed in your app may vary from server to server.